# When using R's apply function can I also get the index of the item being processed?

Tags: r

In javascript, I am used to using the map function at this point. The callback for the map function takes two (really, three) arguments: the value and the index, like so:

```
someArray.map((value, index) => { // do stuff })
```

I'm new to R, but have noticed that the `apply` method is similar in that you provide some sort of data structure and then a function to run on each data element.

However, I haven't seen in the docs anywhere where I can let that function be aware of the index. Something like:

```
lapply(some_list, function(val, idx) print(idx))
```

which I would hope to output:

```
1
2
.
.
.
n - length of list
```

Am I missing something, or is this not possible in R?

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: You could use a for loop, which might not be optimal from a performance point of view, but would let you keep track of the loop index.

Comment: Yes @TimBiegeleisen, I thought about that as well, but was curious to know  whether this is actually not possible in R. Would seem odd given that this "mapping" pattern is mostly there.